# gnokii sometimes Initialization failed

Tags: centos, usb, sms, failed, sms-gateway

I have problem with gnokii 0.6.31 +usb huawei e220 (centos 6.4 64 bit)
Normaly works ok.

```
echo "SMS from Huawei" | gnokii --phone huawei --config /etc/gnokiirc --sendsms 1234567890
GNOKII Version 0.6.31
Send succeeded with reference -1!
```

But after a couple of days days it stops working and I get the following error condition:

```
echo "SMS from Huawei" | gnokii --phone huawei --config /etc/gnokiirc --sendsms 1234567890
GNOKII Version 0.6.31
Initialization failed (11)
Telephone interface init failed: Command timed out.
Quitting.
```

Only solution I know is to unplug and reconnect the Huawei USB modem and then it will work again.

I try with this, but that doesn't work:

```
echo '2-1' |tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
sleep 20
echo '2-1' |tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

I got the same output whenever it's working or not

```
gnokii --identify
GNOKII Version 0.6.31
Apparently you didn't configure gnokii. Please do it prior to using it.
You can get some clues from comments included in sample config file or give
a try with gnokii-configure utility included in gnokii distribution.
IMEI         : Unknown
Manufacturer : Unknown
Model        : Unknown
Product name : Unknown
Revision     : Unknown
```

info from /var/log/messages

```
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: USB Serial support registered for generic
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: usbserial: USB Serial Driver core
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: option 2-1.8:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: usb 2-1.8: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: option 2-1.8:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: usb 2-1.8: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver option
Jun 15 12:36:02 chi kernel: option: v0.7.2:USB Driver for GSM modems
```

The output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
```

config:

```
[global]
port = none
model = fake
initlength = default
connection = serial
use_locking = no
serial_baudrate = 9600
smsc_timeout = 10

[xgnokii]
allow_breakage = 0

[gnokiid]
bindir = /usr/local/sbin/

[connect_script]
TELEPHONE = 12345678

[phone_huawei]
model = AT
port = /dev/ttyUSB1
connection = serial
```

Comment: this solve my problem:
i add new kernel from repository and disable autosuspend to all usb devices
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend; do echo -1 > $i; done
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level; do echo on > $i; done

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem:

I add new kernel from repository and disable autosuspend to all usb devices:

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend; do
    echo -1 > $i;
done
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level; do
    echo on > $i;
done
```